# Abstract data type that has "include" "remove" and "is in" and only those

Tags: data-structure, data-types

In a data structures course, we see trees, balanced trees, hash tables. These have an important thing in common: we can use them to keep a collection of elements (with operations add and remove) and test for an element in the data structure.

I want to use them to define a "overarching" abstract data type, with each of them as an implementation. Is there a name for this ADT?

The set ADT unfortunately supports more operations (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)#Operations)

Comment: I don't think there exists a standard type that matches that description, but there is no reason you can't follow your plan anyway with a customized name.

Comment: I'd be curious to hear why you're looking this ADT. How are you planning on using it in your class?

Comment: i will use it because we will be implementing it many different ways: with list, ordered list, tree, dictionary. It is just a small callback to the fact that we have many solutions to the same problem, and also a way to drill the concept of ADT

Comment: "The set ADT unfortunately supports more operations" gives Wikipedia a lot of credence. I'm not confident that there is a canonical definition of "*THE* set ADT". Yes, there are other things you can typically do with sets, but you don't have to introduce those operations.

Comment: Yes, I am beginning to think (see bag bellow) that these ADTs have many definitions, and I can just call it "set" or "bag" and define it as I please

Comment: A set, by definition, cannot contain multiple copies of the same item. A multiset, or a "bag" (at least in my intuition) can. Can your data structures? That is an important difference that can confuse your students.

Comment: Of course it depends on how you define "insert" and "remove" whether there is any difference between a set and a bag. In fact, a set can probably be built from a bag just by reimplementing "remove". The question is what happens if you execute isContained after remove. And an interesting implementation of a bag is as a hash map where the "values" inserted are the keys, mapped to positive ints.

Answer (score 3):

Carrano, *Data Abstraction & Problem Solving with C++: Walls and Mirrors* begins by introducing a simple ADT kind of like you're talking about, called a "Bag". But it is not used as a base class for later examples (e.g., trees, et. al.). From Sec. 1.5:

[image]

Comment: Yes, a Bag is a good choice, but "frequencyOf"  is probably inessential to the concept. Also there is no reason that Bag couldn't be a base class of other "collection" ADTs.

Answer (score 0):

Some data structure texts I've seen use "bag" as a generalization of stack/queue/deque: can add items (repetitions allowed), can extract items (no order assumed, i.e. LIFO, FIFO; same sequence of insertions/extractions could give a different output sequence), ask if it is full. No "check if element is present", though. Perhaps what you are looking for is a set or multiset.